# How do I load assets from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, ruby-on-rails-2, redmine-plugins, ruby-1.8.7

Can anyone help me? I don't know how to add assets(js, stylesheets, images) and views from my gem to the rails environment during runtime. This result to template not found errors whenever I'm trying to access url paths indicated by the routes.rb of my gem.

The gems contain some redmine plugins. What we're doing is turning all the app's plugins to gems.

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

```
Environment:
-> Ruby 1.8.7
-> Rails 2.2.2
-> Redmine 0.8
```

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "assets"?

Comment: hi, assets like stylesheets, javascripts, images and views. Sorry I forgot to specify.